# icon in chrome tab indicates loading although page has loaded already

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, requirejs, progress-bar

I have a web app which uses requireJS and Google Maps API. Sometimes tab icon in chrome browser displays usual favicon, sometimes a progress indicator, although page has already been loaded. I can't imagine what might be the cause. Any help appreciated, thanks.